# Backing up a Serverless Framework deployment

Tags: serverless-framework

I'm familiar with [Terraform](https://terraform.io) and its `terraform.tfstate` file where it keeps track of which local resource identifiers map to which remote resources. I've noticed that there is a `.serverless` directory on my machine which seems to contain files such as CloudFormation templates and ZIP files containing Lambda code.

Suppose I create and deploy a project from my laptop, and Serverless spins up `fooxyz.cloudfront.net` which points to a Lambda function `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:handleRequest456`. If I naively try to run Serverless again from another machine (or if I `git clean` my working directory), it'll spin up a new CloudFront endpoint since it doesn't know that `fooxyz.cloudfront.net` already represents the same application. I'm looking to back up the state it keeps internally, so that it modifies an existing resource rather than creates a new one. (The equivalent in Terraform would be to back up the `terraform.tfstate` file.)

**If I wished to back up or restore a Serverless deployment state, which files would I back up?** In the case of AWS, it seems like I should be backing up the CloudFormation templates; I don't want to back up the Lambda code since it's directly generated from the source. However, I'm likely going to use more than just AWS in the future, and so don't want to "special-case" the CloudFormation templates if at all possible.

How can I back up only the files I cannot regenerate?

Comment: It looks like Serverless automatically backs up the CloudFormation templates to S3. The bucket name can be [configured](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/) using the `deploymentBucket` key in _serverless.yml_. However, I suspect that this only backs up the AWS config, whereas I'd also like to keep the state of any other providers.

Comment: I don't understand this question. The serverless.yml and the source code is more than enough to deploy exactly the same solution in another Cloud account. You just need to avoid hard-coding keys or endpoints.

Comment: Good point, my intent is not clear from what I wrote. I'm editing the question now.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is **If I or a colleague checks out the serverless code from git on a different machine, will we still be able to deploy and update the same lambda functions and the same API gateway endpoints?**

And the answer to that is yes! Serverless keeps track of all of that for you within their files. Unless you run **serverless destroy** - no operation will create a new lambda or api endpoint.

My team and I are using this method: we commit all code to a git repo and one of us checks it out and deploys a function or the entire thing and it updates the existing set of functions properly. If you setup an environment file - that's all you need to worry about really. And I recommend leaving it outside of git entirely.

Comment: Is that true for resources as well? I'm running a `Bucket already exists` error.

Answer (score 0):

For AWS; Serverless Framework keeps track of your deployment via Cloudformation (CF) parameters/identifiers which are specific to an account/region.  The CF stack templates are uploaded to an (auto-generated) S3 bucket so it's already backed up for you.

So all you really need to have is the original deployment code in a git repo and have access to your keys.  Everything else is already backed up for you.